# Error in writeLines: invalid 'text' argument

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a line based on the below matrix,

```
print(mat)

     [,1]        [,2]     
[1,] "wesd"     "2.0E-5" 
[2,] "lesd"     "8.0E-8" 
[3,] "nf"       "16.0"   
[4,] "ldop"     "1.25E-6"
[5,] "lsop"     "2.0E-7" 
[6,] "esdoxide" "1.0"    
[7,] "gns"      "1.0"
```

Below is my code, .

```
ipFile = 'text.txt'
fConn <- file(ipFile,open="w")
paramname <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g")
for(a in 1:length(paramname)) {
        
        
          tmpvar = 1
        #Using the matrix value printed above
          writeLines(c('parameters ',mat[a,1],'_',as.character(tmpvar),'=',as.character(mat[a,2]),'\n'),con=fConn,sep="")
        
      a=a+1
}

   close(fconn)
```

I'm getting the below Error,

```
Error in writeLines: invalid 'text' argument
```

I tried to change the integer values used in writeLines to as.character but no hope. And meanwhile when I try to run the above code in the console it works well (by removing the conn=fconn argument in the writeLines code). This code doesn't work when I try to run from the rstudio app.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on my side and it worked

```
data= cbind(c( "wesd" , "lesd"  , "nf" ,"ldop" ,"lsop" , "esdoxide", "gns"),c( "2.0E-5" ,  "8.0E-8" , "16.0" , "1.25E-6",  "2.0E-7" , "1.0" ,  "1.0"))
ipFile = 'text.txt'
fConn <- file(ipFile,open="w")
paramname <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g")
for(a in 1:length(paramname)) {
  
  
  tmpvar = 1
  #Using the matrix value printed above
  writeLines(c('parameters ',data[a,1],'_',as.character(tmpvar),'=',as.character(data[a,2]),'\n'),con=fConn,sep="")
  
  a=a+1
}

close(fConn)
```

Did it help?

Comment: No this is not working for me. Throwing Subscript bound error. I don't think I need to do cbind here. Since cbind merges everything it to a single column.

Comment: it doesn't work when I run from the rstudio app. But it works when I run through console!

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure Why but when I used paste while running in rstudio application, the code worked well!

```
writeLines(c('parameters ',paste(mat[a,1],'_',as.character(tmpvar),'=',as.character(mat[a,2])),'\n'),con=fConn,sep="")
```